# Problem with insert product into database

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-insert

I am trying to learn how to C#.

I want to add a product to my database using `System.Data.SqlClient` and `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`.

At the moment I have a database class :

```
public SqlConnection connection()
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.DataSource = "DESKTOP-UPVVOJP";
    builder.InitialCatalog = "Lagersystem";
    builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

    // Console.WriteLine(builder);
    return new SqlConnection(builder.ToString());
}
```

A product class :

```
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProductCreatedDate { get; set; }
```

In my program I try to `AddProduct` through a method :

```
static void AddProduct(string name)
{
    Database db = new Database();

    SqlConnection conn = db.connection();
        
    try
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(@ProductName, @ProductCreatedDate)", conn))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductName", name));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ProductCreatedDate", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));

            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            Console.WriteLine(name + " Tilføjet");
        }
    }
    catch (ArgumentException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I call this method from main :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("INPUT ProductName :");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string name = input.ToString();

        try
        {
            AddProduct(name); // Add the data to the SQL database.
            Console.WriteLine("Product created!");
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input error");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug my program, I can follow that the input I enter is going through the entire program, down to the `AddProduct(name);` method. Everything there seems fine.

But somehow it does not add, and everything I try, I still end up in the catch block `Console.WriteLine("Input error");`.

Can anyone here help me a bit to understand where I am going wrong, or what is failing me on the way here?

If its any help, my database has a table `Products` like this:

```
ProductID - int - primary key - Identity(1, 1) - no null
ProductName - nvarchar(32) - no null
ProductCreatedDate - Datetime - no null
```

Comment: Don't `ToString` the date - insert it directly.

Comment: Do not write useless try/catch. Catch has a parameter _catch(Exception ex)_ then in the ex passed there are many informations about the error. Try to write out the _ex.Message_ property at least. I think that the error is caused by your passing a DateTime variable as a string. AddWithValue takes the type passes to build the parameter but if the database column expects a date then passing a string will result often in an error

Comment: Second point. Put the using statement around the connection. This is the main object that keeps unmanaged resources and that needs to be disposed as soon as possible.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns an integer indicating the number of rows changed.  When you have a primary key  each key must be unique.  When you do an Insert and the key already exists you will get a zero returned from the execute and must use Update.  When you do an Update and the key does not exist you also will get a zero returned and then must use Insert.

Comment: Your second parameter is missing the `@` when added to the command. You could for instance instead of printing just `input error` catch the exception with `catch (Exception ex)` and then print `ex.Message` which might give you a hint, what's going wrong ...

Comment: And eventhough, SQLServer *should*  be able to parse a valid date format from string to date time, don't convert your datetime to string, just use the datetime directly in the parameter. And to be on the safe side, you should create parameters explicitely specifying their type. https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much, it works now.

It seems i can not wrap my using around my connection, i am getting connection to database error by doing so.

```
        static void AddProduct(string name)
        {
            Database db = new Database();
            SqlConnection conn = db.connection();
            
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(@ProductName, @ProductCreatedDate)", conn))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductName", name));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductCreatedDate", DateTime.Now));
                    conn.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine(name + " Tilføjet");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
```

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //TryCreateTable();
            DisplayProducts();
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("INPUT ProductName :");
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                string name = input.ToString();
                try
                {
                    AddProduct(name); // Add the data to the SQL database.
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
```

Comment: It might be helpful to other programmers if you posted your improved code here in your self-answer

Comment: You've posted so much but at no time did you _actually_ post the error message. Please do not ask a question, let alone answer a question, without the error message